# Piecewise plotting in Datashader - data exceeds my ram

Tags: python, datashader

So I'm trying out Datashader, which looks and perform great. However, all the examples must be done either with a machine with massive ram, or just not that large datasets. Because I blow up my 16gb ram when I try to do some big plots. I have no doubt Datashader can handle the data, however, I am at loss on how I can load it and plot it piecewise.

So to be clear, its not during plotting, but actually via reading from database this fails - however, since Datashader is a library for plotting really big data, there has to be some methods instead of load everything in a df and pass it in?

My code as it is now:

```
from colorcet import fire
import psycopg2
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf
con = getCon()
query = """SELECT latitude, longitude FROM mydatabasetable"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
agg = cvs.points(df, 'longitude', 'latitude')
img = tf.shade(agg, cmap=['lightblue', 'darkblue'], how='log')
```

Is it for example possible to call the cvs.points method several times (and thus divide my data into several bits?)

Answer (score 1):

Datashader supports Pandas, Dask, and CUDA dataframes (cuDF), each with their own strengths and limitations. Pandas is a good default choice, but a Pandas DataFrame is all loaded into memory at once, which will indeed limit how large a dataset you can process. A Dask dataframe does not have that limitation; Dask defines chunks and does not need to load them all in at once. We routinely use Datashader+Dask with chunked-based file formats like Parquet to process much larger datasets than will fit in memory; see e.g. https://examples.pyviz.org/nyc_taxi/dashboard.html (but remove `.persist()` to make it operate out of core). `Dask.DataFrame` has a `read_sql_table` method, but I haven't verified that it operates out of core the way Parquet does; if it does you should be in business!